# Normal Distribution $r-1$ th moment with absolute value

Tags: integration, statistics, normal-distribution, absolute-value

I was stuck for this problem whole night and I tried numerical solution using MATLAB and the following result seems hold

for x follow normal N(0,1) and for any positive number (not integer only) r>1, we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \! \frac{|x|^r}{x} \, \mathrm{d}\Phi({x}) =0$$
where $\Phi({x})$ is the CDF for standardize normal.

I tried various r = 1.5, 2.5 numerically, and they are all equal to zero.

Of course when r is positive even integer, this result is trivial. But I am stuck with the general r>0 case, especially for r is NOT integer.

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: After rewriting $d\Phi(x)$ as $\Phi'(x) dx$, you will see that you are integrating an odd function.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMontgomery-Smith for your quick answer! If I rewrite as you suggested, I am not 100% sure how to approach the absolute value, and also there is exponential function exp(-x^{2} /2), can you elaborate why it's an odd function? Thank you!

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith, I see why it's an odd function! Just need to figure out why the integration is 0 if it's an odd function

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definite_Integral_of_Odd_Function

Answer (score 0):

Let $I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{|x|^r}{x} \phi(x) dx; \quad r>0$.
Since the integrand is an even function through out the domain, we can write it as,
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
I &=&  2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^r}{x} \phi(x) dx\\
&=&  2\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{r-1} \phi(x) dx\\
&=& \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{r-1} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2} dx\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
let $u = x^2 / 2$, so that $du = xdx$.
Now,
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
I &=& \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int_0^{\infty} (2u)^{\frac{r-2}{2}} e^{-u} du\\
&=& \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} 2^{\frac{r-2}{2}} \int_0^{\infty} u^{\frac{r}{2} - 1} e^{-u} du\\
&=& \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} 2^{\frac{r-2}{2}} \Gamma\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$